# Does the verb "humble" exist in spanish?

Tags: traducción

Consider the phrase:

> This experience **humbled** me.

I think that it has a different meaning than

> This experience **humilliated** me

Is there a similar verb for this in Spanish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't get a specific verb right now but let me offer two *locuciones verbales*. I think that the equivalent in English are named *phrasal verbs*.

According to the DLE

> [bajarle a alguien los humos](https://dle.rae.es/humo)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Domar su altivez.

According to the Oxford Dictionary ([and the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/sitio?m=form) as well)

> [poner en su sitio](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/poner_en_su_sitio)
> LOCUCIÓN
>
> 1. Hacer saber claramente a una persona cuál es su situación o función en un lugar y no consentirle un comportamiento inadecuado cuando se excede en sus atribuciones o actúa con excesiva familiaridad.
>
> EN (translation by me)
>
> 1. Show someone clearly what is his place or function in a situation and do not let him behave inadequately when he exceeds his attributions or acts with excesive familiarity.

If you check the [meaning of humble](https://www.lexico.com/definition/humble?locale=es) as a verb in the Oxford Dictionary

> Cause (someone) to feel less important or proud.

or in [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humble?q=humbled)

> to make someone understand that they are not as important or special as they  thought

When the DLE states that you show someone what is his place, you're letting him know what is his real importance in relation with others in a specific situation. The first expression *bajarle a alguien los humos* is a synonym of *poner a alguien en su sitio*.

Applying those in your sentences, it would be

> La experiencia me bajó los humos.
> La experiencia me puso en mi sitio.

Comment: poner en su sitio is to put someone in his/her/their place

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, humble (humilde) is used as an adjective in Spanish but for the phrase

> This experience humbled me.

You could write something like

> This experience made me humble = Esta experiencia me hizo humilde

Or

> This experience taught me something = Esta experiencia me enseño algo

Comment: OP no pregunta si puede usar "humilde" como verbo en español, sino un verbo equivalente a "to humble". La segunda opción que presentas no tiene que ver con la frase que se pretende traducir, no es lo mismo "humble" que "taught me something".

Comment: @RubioRic My dictionary says that "to humble" is: *dar una lección de humildad*, so that's not far off.

Comment: @nopaltepec De "enseñarme algo" a "dar una lección de humildad" va un salto bastante grande. No hay ni una palabra en común! Tu paralelismo es más o menos correcto pero en ambas frases no hay ni una sola palabra en común!